# A proof by strong induction for a recurrences defining function

Tags: induction

> **Problem:** Consider the following recurrences defining function, $$f_2(n) = \lbrace 1\ if\ n = 0;\ 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_2(i)\ if\ n >
>  0\rbrace, f_2: N \to N $$
>
> Prove $f_2(n) = 2^n$

My attempt: Proof by strong induction. so,

**Base Cases**: $$n = 0 \Rightarrow f_2(0) = 1 = 2^0,\ f_2(0)\ holds\\n = 1 \Rightarrow f_2(1) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_2(i) = 2 = 2^1,\ f_2(1)\ holds$$

**Inductive step:** let $n\ge2$. suppose $$f_2(j) = 2^j$$ whenever $0\le j < n$ (IH)

***WTP*:** $f_2(n) = 2^n$, so

$$f_2(n) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_2(i)$$
$$= 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$$ by (IH)
$$= 1 + (2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^{n-1})$$

The next part is where I don't quite get what to do next. I know I have to somehow simplify that to $2^n$ but I have no idea how to do that. If anyone can help me with that that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Muitlply the part inside the parentheses by $2 -1$

Answer (score 1):

Either you know the result on geometric series saying that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a^i =\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$ which concludes your proof.

Or, another way is to notice that $$f_2(n)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f_2(i)=\left(1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}f_2(i)\right)+f_2(n-1)=f_2(n-1)+f_2(n-1).$$
And you should be able to conclude from here.